# Meaning behind Metropolis-Hastings Acceptance Ratio

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains, data-analysis

I have a question regarding the the term in the acceptance ratio of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm (Refer to the link to a screenshot). Is the $\mid$ in $g(x_t \mid X^*)$ supposed to mean it's a conditional probability? Does this mean that the proposal density is supposed to be a conditional density? If so, how should I interpret $g(x_t \mid X^*)$?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnuP5.png)

Comment: try to use mathjax instead of images

Comment: The $g(x \mid y)$ is the proposal distribution for $x$ given the previous state $y$. In general this may depend nontrivially on $y$.

Comment: What about g(y |x)? Would this just be the proposal distribution for y given the future state x? I ask, because this doesn't make much sense for an outcome to be conditioned upon a future outcome

Comment: So intuitively, you can best think of g(x|y) as the proposal given the previous state y. Easiest example to come to mind would be choosing g(x|y) as a Gaussian with mean y and some std. g(y|x) is just changing variable names, so previous state would be x here.

Comment: what about g(y|x) though? the acceptance ratio incorporates the ratio between g(x|y) and g(y|x). If y is the previous state, what would it mean to condition a previous state given a future state?

Comment: You never do that in M-H or really in MCMC in general. What is going on in the acceptance ratio is obtaining a balance between the probability current from x to y and the current from y to x when the present distribution is the target distribution. Either way the second argument is conceptually the "present" state.